# C# InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, invalidoperationexception

```
Nodo N;  

foreach (string S in listBox_nodos.Items)  
{  
    N = graph.getNodoName(S);  
    string comp = (string) listBox_nodos.SelectedItem;  
    if (comp == S)  
        System.Console.WriteLine(N.NAME);  
}
```

I get `InvalidOperationException` and the application crashes.
Can't get why. Any help? Thanks.

EDIT: The 'N.NAME' prints! And then goes the crash.
EDIT2: I've tried to catch the Exception, the application crashes anyway.

Comment: you may find the exception is being generated somewhere else entirely. can you post the entire exception message?

Comment: Exception message: A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: I meant more than that - stack trace, etc.

Comment: Dont know how to get that info.  Thanks for the help, the exception has disapeared. I changed .Item to .SelectedItems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At which line do you get the exception? Without knowing what datatype `listBox_nodos` has, my first guess w2ould be that `Items` does not contain a lot of `string`s, but rather `ListBoxItem`s

```
foreach (var item in listBox_nodos.Items)  
{  
    N = graph.getNodoName(item.Value); // or .SomethingElse
```

Comment: When i add items to the listbox, they are strings.  
I guess i have to learn more about listbox's.

Comment: Problem solved. I changed listBox_nodos.Items to listBox_nodos.SelectedItems. But still, i cant get the reason for the Exception

Comment: The foreach loop throws this exception when you modify the Items collection inside the loop.  Using SelectedItems instead could indeed avoid that, as long as you don't change the selected items.

Comment: @nobugz Thanks, now i got the reason for the Exception.

Comment: You can also try using Linq to create a copy of the collection via `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` in your `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

- as mentioned before, the full exception would be nice to see (if in the VS debugger, you can get it from the exception helper dialog or the $exception entry in Debug -> Windows -> Locals).  Worst-case you should be able to try { .. } catch (Exception ex) { System.Console.WriteLine(ex); (Exception's ToString includes the stack trace)

  - if you're not sure of the types involved, could get the Items/SelectedItem as IEnumerable/object and then gettype() on them and display that.
- when trying to display things, may also want to try MessageBox.Show just in case the exception is coming from the use of Console for some reason.
- unrelated to the exception, but it looks like you're interating over the listbox items to find the selected item - if that's true, why not just use the selected item directly?

Comment: Thanks for your time! Yes, indeed. I cant put the info here now cus my application has advanced, and the code is completely different. I wasn't using the item directly because the ListBox was just a string Collection that represented an ArrayList of objects. I'm student and this site and comments are helping me very much, thanks for the time really.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem before, also related to selected items. I investigated it extensively and was not able to find a fix. I eventually wound up remaking the form (though I think just the control was necessary) and that seemed to fix it.